# Why doesn't this Python code for powerset work?

Tags: python, scala, recursion

I can't identify anything blatantly wrong with it except that I am trying to do Scala-type operations with Python.

```
def powerset(arr):
        if len(arr) == 0:
            return []
        elif len(arr) > 1:
            return powerset(arr[1:])+[arr[0]]
```

I consistently get a error:

> return powerset(arr[1:])+[arr[0]]
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if len(arr) == 1`

nothing is returned ...

just change it to

```
def powerset(arr):
    if len(arr)>0:
         return powerset(arr[1:])+[arr[0]]
    else:
         return []
```

here is a powerset function from https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

```
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

here is a powerset implementation that uses slightly less magic

```
def powerset(seq):
    """
    Returns all the subsets of this set. This is a generator.
    """
    if len(seq) <= 1:
        yield seq
        yield []
    else:
        for item in powerset(seq[1:]):
            yield [seq[0]]+item
            yield item

print list(powerset([1,2]))
```

Comment: Hrmm yes! Now I have all the cases covered appropriately so the error is gone. But why does it only return the full list back, and not all the actual power sets?

Comment: Ity looks like its just reversing the list ... its been a long time you will have to remind me what a powerset is ... or ill have to google it

Comment: Power set returns all the subsets. [1,2] -> [], [1], [2], [1,2]. I think it has something to do with the fact that it's not appending this item to all the past combinations.

Comment: Right! But I'm trying to code it without any built-in functions.

Answer (score 1):

If arr has only one element, you don't return anything.  This becomes **None**.  Your next-to-last iteration blows up because powerset() is None.

Change one line:

```
elif len(arr) > 1:
```

... becomes ...

```
else:
```